# Compute discrete(sampled) time process noise matrix from continuous time process

Tags: probability-theory

Given continuous time state transition and process noise matrices $A$ and $Q$ , one can compute the 
discrete time (sampled) process noise matrix as follows:
$$
Q(\delta t)=\int\limits_{0}^{\delta t}{{{e}^{A\tau }}Q{{e}^{{{A}^{T}}\tau }}d\tau }
$$

I want to ask why? where does the formula come from?

Comment: Please use a \$ \$ at beginning and the end of formula to make it readable!

Comment: I'm learning how to format the formula.^_^